# Log HTTP and HTTPS browser traffic, decrypting the latter

Tags: firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions, https

Is there a way that I can save all HTTP and HTTPS browser communications (including request, response, full headers and body) to files on my computer?

The HTTPS communications must be saved decrypted.

Ideally I'd be looking for something like an extension for Firefox or Google Chrome.

It must work on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HAR** is HTTP Archive, and is exactly what you want to save (it includes HTTPS unencrypted).

Luckily this is now a basic feature of all major browser (it was not when you asked the question). No more need of third party extensions.

**In Firefox (v41+):**

- Start Firefox Developer Tools in Network mode (Top right menu > Developer > Network, or ctrl-shift-Q)
- Reproduce the target scenario
- Save the capture by right-clicking on the grid and choosing "Save all as HAR"
- Export the capture to a HAR file

**Other browser:**

In recent version of all browser, you can save HAR easily:

https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/

Answer (score 6):

[HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) is a Firefox extension that will do the job.

===EDIT===

Right click the request panel and click "Copy all rows".  Then you can save it to what ever editor you like - Openoffice spreadsheet for example.  Please see the image that I provided.

[image: Answer]

Comment: I don't think so. I've just installed HttpFox 0.8.9, and I can't see any way to save all the logged traffice to files. Please note that I have thousands of HTTP(S) requests, and I'm not willing to click a thousand times to save all of them. Please clarify how you would save all the data using HttpFox.

Comment: I do think so, chief. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @slotistype: Thank you for the clarification image. I didn't know about *Copy all rows* before, so I tried it as you suggested. It was very easy to find it using the image you provided. Unfortunately it doesn't copy the HTTP request and response body, so it is not a solution to my question.

Comment: @pts my bad. Just noticed that. I don't know of another tool, unless you intall something outside of firefox. Good luck

Comment: FYI HttpFox has a *Content* tab where I can view the response body -- except for some requests, for which it says `Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)`. But I need the response body of all requests, so HttpFox can't be a solution to this problem.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is definitely something you should consider even if it is not an extension but a separate application.

Comment: Sorry, Fiddler doesn't work for me. because it requires Microsoft Windows. I have Ubuntu. A browser extension, as I originally asked, would probably work on multiple operating systems.

Comment: Fiddler is available for Linux now.

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer wanting to do this, and none of the answers here suited me because I needed to dump HTTPS response bodies, much like OP.  So, for those who land here like I did, here's what I found.

I eventually landed on [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/), which isn't a Firefox extension, but does accomplish the goal of logging all Firefox traffic.  It's all Python, so I installed it with `pip install mitmproxy` - use a package manger if you like.

Started it up with `mitmproxy` for initial setup/debugging, and then used `mitmdump` to dump the stream once I had it working and refined.

I just set Firefox to use `127.0.0.1:8080` as the proxy server (8080 being mitmproxy's default port), and I saw all my Firefox traffic coming through mitmproxy.  To enable HTTPS traffic, you have to accept the certificate that mitmproxy creates - with the proxy set up, just go to the "magic address" of http://mitm.it in Firefox, click the "Other" button, check the boxes to trust the cert, and hit OK.

To dump the unencrypted response body, I had to use a very simple [inline script](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/scripting/inlinescripts.html):

```
from libmproxy.model import decoded

def response(context, flow):
    with decoded(flow.response):  # automatically decode gzipped responses.
        with open("body.txt","ab") as f:
            f.write(flow.response.content)
```

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/cincodenada/c7f22bf1baefa5cede30) - download it as `save_response.py` and use it with `mitmdump -s save_response.py`.  Response bodies will start piling up in `body.txt`.

mitmproxy also has a number of useful [filters](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/features/filters.html) that you can specify [to mitmdump](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/mitmdump.html) to grab just what you need.

Answer (score 2):

httpFox, httpScoop (Mac only) and httpWatch (IE, Firefox, windows only) are all tools I use for doing this. Additionally you can also try Fiddler (as previosuly suggested) and also if yuo're using a Mac you could try Charles Proxy. My personal favourite is httpWatch (you can easily filter on headers, content, url etc), but this is expensive so may not be an option.

You might also want to look at the [HAR](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/http-archive-specification/) project (HAR stands for HTTP Archive) and is a standards based approach to recording http transactions, headers, content etc. A number of the tools mentioned are able to export thee HAR files for viewing using he HAR Viewer (which you'll be familiar with if you've looked at the waterfall feature in Firebug). In fact, you can use Firebug to generate these files/logs for you as well using NetExport.

FWIW httpScoop is a good method for debugging/tracing HTTP traffic on a wireless network, I wrote an article about doing this some time ago: http://blog.adtools.co.uk/trace-debug-mobile-application-http-requests-using-macos/

Comment: Which of the tools you mention can save a dump of all logged communication to disk? httpFox can't. httpScoop is Mac-only, and I was asking for a Linux solution. httpWatch is Windows-only, and I was asking for a Linux solution. Fiddler is Windows-only, and I was asking for a Linux solution. Charles Proxy is Mac-only, and I was asking for a Linux solution. Thank you for mentioning Firebug+NetExport, that can potentially work.

Comment: Firebug+NetExport work like a charm for me on Linux. They export SSL traffic unencrypted (just as I wished). I'd be happy to accept your answer, but please remove all other propositions (or move them to a separate answer) first.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) can be used to capture network packets, including things in the http protocol layer, and save them to your computer.  It can also capture https information, but I doubt that you'd be able to configure it to decrypt anything.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Wireshark, but it useless as an answer to my question, since it doesn't save the HTTPS stream decrypted.

Comment: Wireshark can decrypt SSL traffic since one of the last versions **if you have the private server certificate**.

Comment: I don't have the private server certificate.